# How do I install a Windows Service Application

Tags: deployment, windows-services, installutil

I am having a problem installing a Windows Service application on my computer. If I am successful I expect to see my service listed under **Computer Management** – **Services and Application** – **Services**.

I first try to click on my exe. I get this message:

> Cannot start service from the command line or a debugger. A Windows Service must first be installed (using installutil.exe) and then started with the ServiceExplorer, Windows Service Adminstration tool or the Net Start command.

So I tried to using the `installutil` tool. From a command prompt I typed *installutil ooaservice.exe*. I get a message

> Exception occurred while initializing the installation:
>   System.badimageformatexception: could not load file or assembly ‘file///(the path to my exe follows)ooaservice.exe’ or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the  currently loaded one and cannot be loaded…

I also tried to build a setup project. The setup installs successfully  but the service is not listed as a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be several versions of .NET frameworks installed on your machine, try to use the highest version of `installutil` to install.

On my machine it is under `E:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe`.